# CSS - z-index:-1 breaking in google chrome

Tags: z-index

Basically creating a webpage with a dropdown menu I wrote following a tutorial. My page layout  consists of 3 separate tables which include 1 for the title/banner, one for the drop down menu and one for the body/content.

The problem I am having first off is that when I scroll over my drop-down menu it drops behind my body/content table. I found a fix for this which was to include z-index:-1. This worked perfectly in IE but after testing it in chrome it prevented links and iframes to be interacted with on the content/body table.

```
#bodytable {width:1100px;
        height:100%;
        margin:auto;
        position:relative;
        top:10px;
        z-index:-1;
        }
```

The entire .css code can be found here:

http://pastebin.com/T97JAjQ8

Comment: We need more than just that block

Answer (score 2):

Try giving them each a positive z-index value.  Obviously the higher numbes will be "on top" of the other with lesser value.  Instaed of giving a table "-1", give it something positive, like 10 and make the dropdown menus "20".  You can even set the z-index of the body, to 0 as a baseline.

I haven't confirmed this, but it could be that chrome doesn't like negative z-index values.

Answer (score 0):

Giving Negative z-index makes your element to go under body or wrapper div and hence, prevent them to be interacted because the body element is on the top of that table when you click the event occurs on the body tag not table tag. You have to give positive z-index value. Default stack order of elements is determined the position where the element is defined. For example, your table will be have a larger z-index value if it is defined after menu div. You can fix your problem by changing only the current stack order. By just changing that negative value to positive.

```
element {
z-index:1;
}
```

The above code will set the target element to be on top of others beside the current stack order.